# How do I display XML data in SQL in HTML

Tags: c#, sql, xml-parsing

I am working on redesigning an old application that stored content in sql as xml data. I know that if I have a file I can use this to display the data in HTML:

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlfile.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Now, lets say I have a table in SQL. In a column I have the contents of "xmlfile.xml". How can I go about displaying that data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for specific field in the xml, SQL Server can query fields of a xml tag inside a sql server column row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks iefpw, I will look into this. I also had a good friend point me in the directon of XSLT. I have never used it before but I think I will try it out.